# jquery Auto complete label issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

[image]

When Enter 1 Character , its showing Blank, Labels are Missing in Auto Completed. How can i Set the label for Autocomplete. But Values are coming.
This is the form field with input type text.

```
<span>
<img  src="images/author2.jpg" width="50" />  //in Database i have profilepic/userimage.jpg and the image shown in above is a static image.
<input class="searchStudent" type="text" autocomplete="off">
</span>
```

I have entered letter "A" and the response is coming as a array.i want to show the photo and names of the user how can i do that...?

This is my from script to get the details:

```
/*Search Student starts here*/
$(document).on("focus keyup", "input.searchStudent", function (event) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: 'gdcontroller.php?action=search',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.value = ui.item.label;
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.value = ui.item.label;
        }

    });
});
/*Search Student ends here*/
```

This is my controller,here I am searching available students with name "A" and fetching their details:

```
if($_GET['action']=="search" && $_GET['term']!='')
{
    $keysearch = $_GET['term'];
    $studentValue = trim($_GET['studentname']);

    $studentsQuery =$conn->query('select s.student_pid,i.email,s.student_email,s.student_fname,s.student_lname,s.profile_pic from r_job_invitations i 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_students s ON i.email = s.student_email where i.id_job =54 and accounttype = 1 and inv_res = 1 and student_fname LIKE "'.$keysearch.'%" OR student_lname LIKE "'.$keysearch.'%" ')or die(mysqli_error());

    $studentData = array();
    while($student = $studentsQuery->fetch_assoc()){
        $studentData[]= $student;
    }
    echo json_encode($studentData);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response should be a JSON object (array) where each item is an object with `id`, `label` and `value` keys.

Each item in your `$studentData` array should have these keys in order for the autocomplete to show the data.

I'm not sure which of them you should like to display, but you can try this for example:

```
    while($student = $studentsQuery->fetch_assoc()){
        $student['id'] = $student['student_pid'];
        $student['label'] = $student['student_fname'];
        $student['value'] = $student['student_fname'];
        $studentData[]= $student;
    }
```

You should play with these values to display what you want.

Answer (score 3):

try this function mysql_real_escape_string()